# MySQL won't connect on EC2 deploying with Rubber

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I'm using rubber to deploy a rails application and am having trouble connecting to MySQL. Do I have to manually setup MySQL on EC2 or should Rubber have already had done that? 
While this isn't all that helpful, here is log output when rake is ran:

```
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] 
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] Access denied for user ''@'db01.memepluspl.us' to database 'meme_plus_plus_production'
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] 
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] 
 ** [out :: db01.memepluspl.us] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case, the app name I had input in rubber.yml was actually different then the actual app name(the project files retains placeholder name)...

I ssh'd into the instance, looked for `current/` and `cat config/database.yml`
then just tried running the connect command rake would try to run from the stuff there and the error was there, so I'd suggest trying to better debug what's going on

I guessed I had to change the rubber-mysql.yml configs... Im recreating the staging stuff now, I think it should at least pass through this issue.. gl

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is having this problem, it is because mysql now has default anonymous users added with limited access.

The problem is discussed [here](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/issues/185).

The first solution there is not comprehensive enough, you need the one at the end which deletes all anonymous users (not just localhost). This is because MYSQL will authenticate on HOST before the USER, so a anonymous user ''@'your.host.com' will take priority over 'dbuser'@'your.host.com' (documented in [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connection-access.html)) and rubber will be trying to connect with the full hostname.

Edit your **./config/rubber/deploy-mysql.yml:**

```
rubber.sudo_script "create_master_db", <<-ENDSCRIPT
  mysql -u root -e "create database #{env.db_name};"
  mysql -u root -e "delete from mysql.user where user='';"   <<-- ADD THIS LINE
  ...
ENDSCRIPT
```

Comment: Marvelous, thank you! This pointed out the anon user "issue" so I just ran mysql_secure_installation to "secure" my installation. Also, I am using MariaDB on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know rudder much but it looks it's missing some configuration. There is no user specified and probably no password either.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure where to configure it at. As far as I understood, Rubber took care of this. In the rubber-mysql.yml file, there is some configuration available but I have not changed this. I have left it with the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Rubber at all so I don't know if it should have created your MySQL account for you, but here is how to do it manually:

```
mysql -u root
mysql> grant all on meme_plus_plus_production.* to 'user'@'db01.memepluspl.us' identified by 'password';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> exit;
```

You may need to enter a password for the MySSQL root account; for example, on Ubunutu the default is "password".

Note also that my example grants full read and write privileges to every table in the database to the specified user.  Look up the MySQL grant command if you want to use reduced privileges.